# Custom loss function in Keras and output accuracy is incorrect

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

When I make a custom loss function as follow : (just the same as binary_crossentropy)

```
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    ce = K.mean(K.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred), axis=-1)
    return ce
```

And binary_crossentropy in keras/keras/losses.py is:

```
def binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.mean(K.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred), axis=-1)
```

When I run :

```
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])
```

The output is correct.

```
ETA: 6:20 - loss: 0.3697 - acc: 0.8343
```

If I use my custom_loss:

```
model.compile(loss=custom_loss, optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])
```

The output is incorrect:

```
ETA: 10:49 - loss: 0.7651 - acc: 0.0694
```

We can see that the accuracy is incorrect. Why??

Comment: that's definitely strange. Can you modify the `custom_loss` function to: `return losses.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)` and rerun the experiment? `losses` here is a keras package.

Comment: @Vlad-HC Thanks for your advice. It got the correct output：`ETA: 10:29 - loss: 0.7650 - acc: 0.5680`. Why is this happening？

Comment: It's strange that I run the code again using: `return losses.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)`. It got the incorrect output: `ETA: 8:37 - loss: 0.6927 - acc: 0.0597`. I have no idea what happened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is caused the accuracy is not the same function between `loss="binary_crossentropy"` and custom loss function.

if you set `loss='binary_crossentropy'`, metric `"acc"` is same as `'binary_accuracy'`.
But you set custom lossfunction as your code, it's same as `'categorical_accuracy'`.

```
def binary_accuracy(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.mean(K.equal(y_true, K.round(y_pred)), axis=-1)


def categorical_accuracy(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.cast(K.equal(K.argmax(y_true, axis=-1),
                          K.argmax(y_pred, axis=-1)),
                  K.floatx())
```

So If you get the same acc value, you specify keras.metrics.binary_accuracy on your metrics array.

```
from keras.metrics import binary_accuracy

model.compile(loss=custom_loss,
              metrics=[binary_accuracy])
```

Comment: Does this address the different losses, though?

Comment: yes! binary accuracy 

1. calculate element wise accuracy
2. mean these values